What is the largest possible weight a parachute can support? Can parachutes support extremely heavy objects like elephants?
I know that some parachutes can be attached to objects heavier than humans, like weapons, emergency supplies, etc. I also know that some military specially trained dogs are sometimes dropped by parachute in a military operation, attached to their handler or trainer. However, can parachutes support huge, extremely heavy objects, or animals like elephants? Basically, my question is:

Had there ever been an occasion where an object weighing a few tons (or elephants, which usually weigh more than 4 tons) parachuted out of aircraft? I'm asking regardless of it's a military operation or not.
If not, is this physically possible given today's largest and most durable parachutes? Can today's largest parachutes be able to withstand the weight of something similar to an elephant and still function normally/properly (i.e., slow the rate of decent)? If not, is it possible to design a parachute to support massive cargo/occupants?

I know the elephants part is a rather crazy and non-sensical concept, and I know that it would not be reasonable and actually practical to do this, but I'm asking for the conceptualized version of things. Basically, my main question is, what is the greatest weight current parachutes can support? What is the greatest possible weight a parachute can physically withstand?
I'll greatly appreciate any insights into this. Looking forward for an explanation! Thanks in advance!

I feel these questions are getting perilously close to off-topic. There is a clear list in the [help/on-topic] that defines the scope of the site. Increasingly unlikely questions about what can be loaded onto or thrown out of an aircraft do not feature. Before posting a question about  <insert object/animal here> ask yourself what purpose is being served. Why exactly would one parachute an elephant out of an aeroplane?

@CatchAsCatchCan What do you mean by "Increasingly unlikely questions about what can be loaded onto or thrown out of an aircraft do not feature"? This is a question about aviation, and not opinion based because I asked if this has happened before and if this is physically possible.

@CatchAsCatchCan I made it pretty clear that I'm not asking if this is good/bad or if it is fanatically possible. I'm asking if it is possible according to physics and aerodynamics. So I don't see why this is off-topic. If you think this is not possible according to physics, then just post an answer telling me so, rather than downvoting my post.

VtC: This question is not about aviation. It's about parachutes. It's about cargo. D/V: I have D/V as I don't believe it is a useful question AND you show no initial research, both of these are reasons for down voting. These are my opinion and I am as entitled to it as you are to disagree.

As for the question if an elephant has ever been parachuted out of a plane I cannot say, but for the technical part:
Yes, it would be technically possible to parachute an elephant out of a plane. As an example of parachute performance, the SpaceX Dragon 2 re-entry vehicle has a "landing weight" of approximately 7000kg, while an adult African elephant can weight up to 6500kg.
While this would be technically possible, I seriously doubt the sensibility of such a stunt. It would be extremely stressfull to the animal itself, and the operation would require sedation. To safely land the animal, some kind of a crate and/or a cushioning device would be necessary, since the elephant as a massive creature is not "designed" to handle impact loads well.

The Space Shuttle SRBs had an empty mass of about 90000kg and landed under three parachutes, each of which was rated for about 88000kg. A single one of those parachutes could carry 13 elephants. The "how" is not a problem, the issue, as you say in your last paragraph, is "why the frack"?
